# "Please log in to any StackExchange site first"

Tags: support, chat

When I want to go to chat I get this message at the top of the screen, while I'm logged on on at least 5 Firefox tabs! If I remove the message and click on `login` the message comes back. So I can't chat.

Firefox 3.6.18 on Windows XP w/ SP3.

Comment: Have you tried logging out/in again? What does http://chat.stackexchange.com/help say?

Comment: @balpha - Thanks for the suggestion. I always thought that moving away from SE would automagically log off, and I tried that, but maybe I should logoff explicitely, only I can't find a button/link for that on http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Move the mouse cursor over your username on the top; the logout link is in the popup.

Comment: Explicitely logging out doesn't solve the problem; I keep getting the same message when I click on `login` :-(. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: No, just logging out doesn't do the deal -- you'll also have to log back *in* to electronics.se. Also, you didn't answer my other question: What does the diagnostics page say?

Comment: I *couldn't* login: I got the message as soon as I clicked `login` :-(. Diagnostics OK for 1 to 4, 5 was skipped. Doesn't Firefox support DOM storage?? Anyway, the alternative login method on the bottom of the page seems to work. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Well, if DOM storage is disabled, that explains why it didn't work. FF supports it (I think since version 3.5 at least); check `dom.storage.enabled` in `about:config`. Do you have any paranoia plugins installed that would disable it, like NoScript or such?

Comment: dom.storage is enabled. I do have NoScript installed, but everything on SE is enabled.

Comment: @Steven - What is "everything on SE"? Does it include http://or.sstatic.net/, the StackOverflow CDN?  [Kellenjb reports](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1435996#1435996) that Chat works in FF with NoScript and sstatic.net whitelisted.

Comment: @Kevin - everything means `*.stackexchange.com`. And yes, `sstatic.net` is also whitelisted. To make sure NoScript wasn't the culprit I checked "Temporarily allow all this page", but that didn't help.

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled? I get *Test 2: Cookies – failed
You might want to try reloading this page; if this test still fails then (or you have already tried this), you probably have restricted or disabled cookies. For login to work, you must enable HTTP cookies in your browser settings; including JavaScript cookies (not just HTTP-only cookies). Most importantly, this has to work on the StackExchange site where you log in with your OpenId.* on http://chat.stackexchange.com/help when I don't have cookies enabled (using Chrome this time), and can't get past the login.

Comment: Note that I've been using the site all day without cookies...it's only chat that doesn't work.

Comment: @stevenvh, is this still an issue?

Comment: @Kortuk - No, it seems to be solved. Also, all diagnostics on http://chat.stackexchange.com/help now report OK.

Comment: @stevenvh, well, while I wish we knew what the problem was, glad it is working.

Answer (score 1):

See

http://chat.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: balpha suggested this in the first comment, almost a month ago, and the OP [posted a comment](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/728/please-log-in-to-any-stackexchange-site-first#comment-1598) that "Diagnostics OK for 1 to 4, 5 was skipped."  What are you trying to accomplish with this answer?

Comment: this is an unanswered question, so it shows up in our stats as such. It needs a proper answer, not a *comment*